# Can't get SOQL statement to work for related object

Tags: soql, relationships

I have an object `Tourist_Details__c` which has 2 child objects `Contacts` and `Incidents__c`.

I already have a list of `Incidents__c` called `results` and now I need to get a list of all `Tourist_Details__c` where the related incident is in `results`. This is so I can perform some functions on the related `Contact`.

Here is my code:

```
public void anonymise() {
    List<Incident__c> results = 
        [SELECT id, Incident_name__c, Date_of_incident__c, Name, Garda_Name__c 
         FROM Incident__c WHERE Date_of_Incident__c <= :firstDate.Date_Of_Incident__c AND 
        Date_of_Incident__c >= :lastDate.Date_Of_Incident__c];

    for (Incident__c inc : results) {
        inc.Incident_name__c = inc.Name;
        inc.Garda_Name__c = '';
    }
    update results;

    List<Tourist_Details__c> touristDetails = 
        [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM IncidentContacts__r)
         FROM Tourist_Details__c
         WHERE Incident__c in :results];               
}

    for (RELATED_CONTACT : touristDetails) {
    //do something
    }
    update touristDetails;
```

My problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM IncidentContacts__r)
                       ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:28
Didn't understand relationship 'IncidentContacts__r' in FROM part of query 
call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append 
the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or 
the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

For my inner select statement in `touristDetails` I have tried using the object name, API name and also the given Child Relationship Name (shown in code) on the `Contact` field in `Tourist_Details__c` but I always seems to get the same error.

Comment: The Child Relationship Name is the correct choice. The error suggests that this simply isn't the child relationship name. It's shown on the lookup field from the child to the parent.

Comment: Thanks David, you were right. It seems as if my `Tourist_Details__c`object is actually the child so I was incorrect to do an inner SOQL statement

Comment: Great! I'll convert my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For my inner select statement in touristDetails I have tried using the object name, API name and also the given Child Relationship Name (shown in code) on the Contact field in Tourist_Details__c but I always seems to get the same error.

You were on the right track: the Child Relationship Name is always the correct choice when performing a parent-to-child subquery in SOQL. However, the presence of the error indicates that `IncidentContacts__r` just isn't the child relationship name, which is shown on the lookup field from the child to the parent.

Based on your comment, you've discovered that your data is arranged a little differently, so that should resolve the issue.

Comment: @Luke Bray
Another thing to consider - If the field is part of a managed package, the real relationship name has the namespace prepended to the beginning.
You can see on Workbench the full API name including the prepended namespace.